# Add TextView objects to SurfaceView

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to add Textview objects to SurfaceView through canvas or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [`drawPostText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPosText%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) function.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing a reference of your Activity to your SurfaceView by Application class or by public member of your Activity. For example my Solution:

1. I created my surfaceview in RelativeLayout and add there textview also.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout ....>
       <com.package.my.MySurfaceView
               android:....... />
       <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textId
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. In MySurface:

   ```
   TextView tv=(TextView)MyActivity.MyAct.findViewById(R.id.textId);
   tv.offsetLeftAndRight(offsetX);
   tv.offsetTopAndBottom(offsetY);
   tv.setText("Your Text Here");
   ```